# Put a line separator in the output of a command

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

how can I put a line of separation in the output of the command:

```
pacman -Ss linux
```

i get this

```
community/riscv64-linux-gnu-glibc 2.29-1
    GNU C Library RISCV target
community/riscv64-linux-gnu-linux-api-headers 5.0-1
    Kernel headers sanitized for use in userspace (riscv64-linux-gnu)
community/rt-tests 1.3-1 (realtime)
    A collection of latency testing tools for the linux(-rt) kernel
```

I want to get

```
community/riscv64-linux-gnu-glibc 2.29-1
    GNU C Library RISCV target
--
community/riscv64-linux-gnu-linux-api-headers 5.0-1
    Kernel headers sanitized for use in userspace (riscv64-linux-gnu)
--
community/rt-tests 1.3-1 (realtime)
    A collection of latency testing tools for the linux(-rt) kernel
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used grep but the result is messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used pacman, but if you want to **print `--` before each line that doesn't start with a tab**, this awk could do the trick:

```
echo -e '1\n\t2\n3\n\t4\n\t5\n6\n\t7' | awk '{if (NR > 1 && $0 !~ "^\t") print "--"; print $0}'
```

Result:

```
1
    2
--
3
    4
    5
--
6
    7
```

Explanation:

`if ((NR > 1) && ($0 !~ "^\t")) print "--"`: if (row number is greater than 1) and (line does not start with a tab) then print `--`

`print $0`: print the whole line

---

Similarly, if you want to **print `--` after every two lines**, this should do:

```
echo -e '1\n\t2\n3\n\t4\n\t5\n6\n\t7' | awk '{if (NR > 1 && NR % 2 == 1) print "--"; print $0}'
```

Result:

```
1
    2
--
3
    4
--
    5
6
--
    7
```